# Load an nib file at server in the iPhone application

Tags: ios4, iphone, iphone-web-app

**Question**

I want to load a nib file at Server to an application running in Phone.

**My Approach**

I currently pass an xml file from the server to my iPhone applicaiton giving a basic detail of the layout (For eg TableView or Navigation Bar etc)

**Problem with My Approach**

Its a very time consuming and not a generic method for the Dynamically updating/controlling the UI from the server.

So the better way of solving this problem is to have various dynamic nib at the server and load the appropriate .nib file based on flow of application.

Is it possible to load a nib file from the server to my iPhone application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue i have mentioned.

please check the 
Session 117 - Building a Server-driven User Experience
in the WWDC 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything like that would/should be possible. Reason being that Apple has a set User Interface Guideline which are strictly checked during the approval period of an application. If it were possible to add dynamic nibs that would essentially by pass the whole "verification" process me thinks.

Comment: so do you mean that load the nib file from server is not possible. but my current approach could get me in trouble when i submit my app for the approval from Apple.